# jslint complains about __proto__ being a reserved word

Tags: javascript, prototype, constructor, jslint, reserved-words

Here is the code in question:

```
hasOwnProperty: function (obj, prop) {
    var hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        proto;
    if (hasOwn) {
        return hasOwn.call(obj, prop);
    } else {
        proto = obj.__proto__ || obj.constructor.prototype;
        return (prop in obj) && (!(prop in proto) || proto[prop] !== obj[prop]);    
    }
}
```

jslint fails while spitting out this error:

```
Error:
Problem at line 653 character 29: Reserved name '__proto__'.
proto = obj.__proto__ || obj.constructor.prototype;
```

Any ideas/solutions?

Comment: What happens when you change `obj.__proto__` to `obj['__proto__']`?

Comment: `__proto__` is deprecated. See [`__proto__` - MDC Doc Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

Comment: @Josiah yes but `getPrototypeOf` is not well supported. The only reason I'm using `__proto__` is to add support for older browsers that dont support `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @mway that works too but then I get a new error `Problem at line 653 character 29: ['__proto__'] is better written in dot notation.`

Comment: use jshint. it's jslint but for normal devs (read !'Douglas Crockford')

Comment: jshint warns about `__proto__` but at least it is simple to turn off: http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#proto

Answer (score 0):

This seems to keep jsLint quiet:

```
hasOwnProperty: function (obj, prop) {
    var hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        proto = '__proto__';
    if (hasOwn) {
        return hasOwn.call(obj, prop);
    } else {
        proto = obj[proto] || obj.constructor.prototype;
        return (prop in obj) && (!(prop in proto) || proto[prop] !== obj[prop]);    
    }
}
```